# How to delay an action on WP 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing a Windows Phone 8.1 (non SL) application. I have a button with an OnClick event.

When the button is clicked, the user is taken to another page using this:

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(secondPage));
```

What are my options for delaying the navigation? I want to wait half a second before moving the user onto the second page.

I tried `Thread.Sleep()` but I'm getting error saying Unresolved symbol on the word `Thread`.

Plus, should I be using that at all?

Comment: The Windows design guidelines states that page navigation should happen with 500 ms so delaying it doesn't seem like a very good idea. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn391697.aspx

Comment: @BrianRasmussen page navigation was an example :) I'm trying to delay something else in practice, but the principle is the same :)

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarifying. Transition animations might be an option as well depending on what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(500);
```

Windows Phone tries to be as asynchronous as possible. This should work for that purpose.

Edit:
Added the fully qualified namespace. Be sure that the reference is added to the project as well.

Comment: Do you have the namespace in the using? System.Threading.Tasks; Please see my edit. I'm away from my personal computer at the moment. I'll have a look at this soon and get back. I feel like I've used this before.

Comment: Note that within the delayed 500ms, the app will still be active and will accept user input, so you should probably disable all input before the `await` call. Otherwise the user could hit the button twice, or hit two different buttons, etc.